# Getting result 'undefined' in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to display some values using ajax for my asp.net application.

This is my C# code

```c#
[WebMethod]
public static  string   fillvazh(int id)
{
    List<object> Users = new List<object>();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string query = "select Id,Name, PWD,Email,Mobile from Users where active='Y' and PM_Id='" + id + "'  ";
    dt = GetData(query); //Common function for getting data from db using DataAdapter  
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Users.Add(new
        {
            Id = dt.Rows[i]["Id"],
            Name = dt.Rows[i]["Name"],
            PWD = dt.Rows[i]["PWD"],
            Email = dt.Rows[i]["Email"],
            Mobile = dt.Rows[i]["Mobile"],
        }); 
    }
    var json = (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Users));
    return json;
}
```

My Jquery is:

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready( function ( e ) {
       $("[id*=pmid]").click(function () {
         vl = $(this).data("val");
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'Default.aspx/fillvazh',
           data: '{id:'+ vl +'}',
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (result) {
                      var data = result.d;
                      // var data = [{"Id":1,"Name":"Sam","PWD":iu875t,"Email":samjohn@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Titus","PWD":mghjgh76,"Email":titus@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"}]; //Working correctly.
                      var tr;
                      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Id + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Name + "</td>");
                        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].PWD+ "</td>");
                        $('#gvCustomers').append(tr);
                      }           
                   },
                   failure: function (response) {  },
                   error: function (response) { }
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The output of *console.log(data)* is

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Sam","PWD":iu875t,"Email":samjohn@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Titus","PWD":mghjgh76,"Email":titus@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"}]
```

The output is **undefined** 
But when I'm trying to hard code the console data, the output is getting normally, means if I use **result.d** value directly.

```
var data = [{"Id":1,"Name":"Sam","PWD":iu875t,"Email":samjohn@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Titus","PWD":mghjgh76,"Email":titus@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"}];
```

I'm not understanding why the output is still undifined and correct when hard code my json output.

Comment: You say in the working version you use `data.d`, yet in the non working version you appear to just be using the root `data` object...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Please see the updated question. I'm getting correct result when the hard coding the json array to var data.

Comment: It's still not clear. Where is the `d` property in the `data` object?

Comment: are your variable names correct when you are accessing them in javascript from data.??

Comment: @GaganDeep - yes. I'm using the same code in the question.

Comment: isn't your property name UName instead of Name? and same for the others

Comment: are you getting response as undefined ? try data:{id: vl} and  also use cache: false after data

Comment: @GaganDeep - Sorry. It is just a typing error. You can check my updated question.

Comment: @Pavan - I'm getting correct response.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: @GaganDeep - I'm too... This is my headache . Can you help me with any RDP software?

Comment: @TitusRaj: Can you share the output if you write console.log(result); & console.log(result.d); this is surely string formatted json issue. I had faced this while using rest api

Comment: @Pavan - Yes, I'm thinking the same. Here is the screenshot. https://pasteboard.co/HqJLYte.png

Comment: use var data = $.JSON.parse(result.d) . This should solve your problem . In case not then let me know

Comment: @Pavan - I'm getting error, **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined**

Comment: @TitusRaj try $.parseJSON(result.d)   . Also try to parse it on jsonlint.com .It should valid on json lint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the output of console.log(data) is this ?

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Sam","PWD":iu875t,"Email":samjohn@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Titus","PWD":mghjgh76,"Email":titus@domain.com,"mobile":"XXXXXXXX"}]
```

if so, maybe the problem is properties *PWD* and *Email*

```
"PWD":mghjgh76,"Email":titus@domain.com
```

Right format should be:

```
"PWD":"mghjgh76","Email":"titus@domain.com"
```

Then, the solution is, in your C# code, when you add new *object* to *Users*, make sure those properties are string

```
PWD = dt.Rows[i]["PWD"].ToString(),
Email = dt.Rows[i]["Email"].ToString(),
```

As I see in your image you upload, *result.d* is currently in string format, so then you should use $.parseJSON

```
var users = $.parseJSON(result.d);
```

(PWD and Email should be string format like I talk above to make parseJSON work right)

Comment: I just changed the values to string using **ToString()** . Now my result is showing with double quotes. But still the problem is not solved.

Comment: I updated the answer after saw your picture of the result, please test again